# Spring Boot swagger file without UI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a simple service built in Spring Boot that has a simple API.  I've added the springfox libraries to use swagger and the swagger UI, but I do not want my application to serve the UI also.  I just want to get the definition from from `/api/v1/api-docs`

How do I switch off the UI part?  Not adding `swagger-ui` library as a dependency doesn't remove the UI for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the UI and return HTTP code 404. Something similar to below

```
@Controller //note - this is a spring-boot controller, not @RestController
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping ("/swagger/api/v1/api-docs")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request) {
       throw new ResourceNotFoundException(); //Custom Solution

       or 

       throw new NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException(request);
    }
}


@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
        return route(GET("/swagger"), req ->
            ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect("<some 404 page>").build());
    }
}
```

Comment: This will indeed patch the endpoint so it's not available, but all the UI and controllers are still registered inside the application increased startup time, etc.  Was looking for a solution that removed it completely.

Comment: Can you share your pom or graddle file?

Comment: These are the relevant parts:

    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

Comment: What if you remove the reference of "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui"